# How can I access Parallel Port through a printer to print RFID barcode in C#?

Tags: c#, printing, printers, parallel-port

There are two ways using C# that I found on the net:

1. Using CreateFile and WriteFile from win32 api:

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll ")]
   private static extern int CreateFile(
       string lpFileName,
       uint dwDesiredAccess,
       int dwShareMode,
       int lpSecurityAttributes,
       int dwCreationDisposition,
       int dwFlagsAndAttributes,
       int hTemplateFile);

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll ")]
   private static extern bool WriteFile(
     int hFile,
     byte[] lpBuffer,
     int nNumberOfBytesToWrite,
     ref   int lpNumberOfBytesWritten,
     ref   OVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
     );
   iHandle = CreateFile("lpt1 ", 0x40000000, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0);
   byte[] mybyte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Mystring);
   bool b = WriteFile(iHandle, mybyte, mybyte.Length, ref   i, ref   x);
   ```

   It can transport barcode command and print barcode well, but it can not read the status from the parallel port.
2. Using Inpout32.dll:
   There are two main functions:

   - `short Inp32(short PortAddress)`
   - `void Out32(short PortAddress, short data)`

But the parameter's type is `short`; how can I transfer print command String at a time?

Comment: Just guessing here but you might have to `Out32` a 16-bit word at a time yourself if there are no streaming functions. Do you have to access the port directly, or can you go through a driver and print normally?

Comment: I wanna access the port directly."16-bit word at a time", does that mean convert command String into byte[] and then I divide the byte array by 2,and call the function Out32 separately?

Comment: I honestly haven't played with it, but I would guess that is correct. Depending on what the device requires, it might need some control codes sent before or after your string as well.

Comment: I'll have a try,thank you!

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091

Comment: I have read this.It uses Parallel Port or Serial Port?In addition,it has to install driver,right?